# DataIntegrityViolationException when trying to insert an entity in a H2 table

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-boot-test

Using Java 17.0.2 and Spring Boot 3.0.2 (same issue with Spring Boot 2.7.x)

(There is a sample project here: https://github.com/fistons/issue-spring-data-test)

I have an entity and its repository:

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "customers")
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Data
public class Customer {
  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
  private Integer id;

  @Column(name = "name", unique = true, nullable = false, length = 255)
  private String name;

  @Column(name = "region")
  @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
  private Region region;

  public enum Region {
    US,
    EU
  }
}
```

```java
@Repository
public interface CustomerRepository extends JpaRepository<Customer, Integer> {}
```

I created a simple service to insert a new entity in it

```java
@Service
public class CustomerService {

  private final CustomerRepository customerRepository;

  public CustomerService(CustomerRepository customerRepository) {
    this.customerRepository = customerRepository;
  }

  @Transactional
  public Customer createCustomer(String name, Customer.Region region) {

    Customer customer = new Customer();
    customer.setName(name);
    customer.setRegion(region);

    return customerRepository.save(customer);
  }
}
```

I created this test (run using in memory H2 database):

```java
@SpringBootTest
@Transactional
class CustomerServiceTest {

  @Autowired
  private CustomerService customerService;

  @Test
  public void test_createCustomer() {
    Customer createdCustomer = customerService.createCustomer("The Crusher", Customer.Region.EU);

    Assertions.assertEquals(4, createdCustomer.getId(), "Id should match");
    Assertions.assertEquals("The Crusher", createdCustomer.getName(), "Name should match");
    Assertions.assertEquals(Customer.Region.EU, createdCustomer.getRegion(), "Region should match");
  }
}
```

with this data.sql fixture:

```sql
INSERT INTO customers (id, name, region) VALUES (1, 'Dr. Carmack', 'EU'), (2, 'Pinky', 'EU'), (3, 'Revenant', 'EU');
```

I explicitly set `spring.jpa.defer-datasource-initialization: true` in my test application.yml

When I run this test, I've got an exception, and I can't figure why:

```
org.springframework.dao.DataIntegrityViolationException: could not execute statement; SQL [n/a]; constraint ["PRIMARY KEY ON PUBLIC.CUSTOMERS(ID) ( /* key:1 */ 1, 'Dr. Carmack', 'EU')"; SQL statement:
insert into customers (id, name, region) values (default, ?, ?) [23505-214]]
```

When I look at the tests logs, I can see that hibernate create the table with the following request:

```sql
    create table customers (
       id integer generated by default as identity,
        name varchar(255) not null,
        region varchar(255),
        primary key (id)
    )
```

It seems that when there is an insertion in service, the ID should be 4 as there is already 3 inserted rows in my fixture.

Why does it try to assign id `1` ? Did I miss something here?

Comment: Maybe it's suffient if you use `default` in your data.sql

Comment: Using `default` and `@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)` on my ID indeed make the test pass. But I would like set custom ID because I want predicable IDs in my fixture

Answer (score 0):

**GenerationType.IDENTITY**

This GenerationType indicates that the persistence provider must assign primary keys for the entity using a database identity column. IDENTITY column is typically used in SQL Server. This special type column is populated internally by the table itself without using a separate sequence. If underlying database doesn't support IDENTITY column or some similar variant then the persistence provider can choose an alternative appropriate strategy. In this examples we are using H2 database which doesn't support IDENTITY column.

You should consider changing your ID persistance type to GenerationType.AUTO or another one

Comment: When I try with `GenerationType.AUTO` the test fails: the id assigned to the inserted entity is 1. It should be 4 as there is already 3 rows inserted by the fixtures with manually assigned ID

Comment: Make sure your hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto property is set to update

Comment: Sadly I have the same issue, id returned is still 1

Answer (score 0):

How the Ids are generated depends on framework and database. Usualy it's done by Sequences, and the Sequnce doesn't know your inserts, so it starts with 1.
You can annotate the class Customer, which sequence to use and use this sequence for creation in the data.sql to avoid this error.

Answer (score 0):

You insert data using `data.sql` with fixed id values. When you next insert data with JPA the identity column will create the same ids and you'll get a Unique Key Violation.

This happens because the id generation internally uses a sequence and does not consider the values in the table.

You have the following options to fix this:

- Use either ids that won't get generated by the id column, e.g. negative values, or huge values that you will never reach.
- Don't specify the ids in `data.sql` and let the database generate them.
- Configure the database sequence to start with a higher value when creating the table. The [`GENERATED` syntax](http://h2database.com/html/grammar.html#column_definition) for identity columns allows to [specify sequence options](http://h2database.com/html/grammar.html#sequence_option) for this purpose.
  Therefore something like this should do the trick:

```sql
create table customers (
    id integer generated by default as identity (start with 4),
    name varchar(255) not null,
    region varchar(255),
    primary key (id)
)
```